# Background video is not playing in iPad devices

Tags: html, css

Background video is not playing in iPad devices. I've tried to add playsinline as well. Video is playing in browser Mac.

I use this code:

```
<div class="video-container"><video muted loop autoplay playsinline controls="true"><source src="./media/199.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="./media/199.ogv" type="video/ogv">Your browser does not support HTML5 video. </video></div>
```

Comment: can you provide your css code too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what you see? Is it blank with a play button? One possibility is that your iPad is in low-power mode, autoplaying videos never play on iOS in low-power mode.

If the problem is that the video is not auto-playing, note that the `autoplay` directive is very finicky. Adding `muted` by no means guarantees that the video will play. In the past, programmatically playing a muted video was the only way I could get autoplay to work, that code is shown below.

```
// Call this function after the document loads
function onload() {
  document.getElementById('your_video').play();
}
```

It could be a CSS issue where the video has `0px` height. Set the background color and check that you see the change.